# In nodejs 'inspect' acts like a reserved word

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js calling console.log on an object that has an element called `inspect` prints `undefined` even though it still works as an object. I assume this is because node uses inspect internally to print stuff out.

```
var thingTwo = {
  num: 1,
  func: function (x) { 2; },
  inspect: function (x) { "hi"; },
};

console.log(thingTwo);  // undefined
```

To avoid this trap in the future is there a list of other words that break standard functionality?

Comment: Node.js does have an inspect function: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors — what happens if you rename inspect?

Comment: Never used node.js, but doesn't `console.log(thingTwo)` actually write `"[object Object]"`?

Comment: @MaxArt — No. console.log outputs the return value of calling `inspect()` on an object (if it has an inspect method).

Comment: @James Brooks is right Seems to cause an issue. If inspect is renamed `console.log` works

Comment: Your code actuallly misses a return statement. Because of that, nothing is returned from `inspect()` (or rather, undefined) and "undefined" is printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cool, this piqued my curiosity and indeed, there is an undocumented feature where an object can provide it's own `inspect` method. The relevant code in [util.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ff140075738dc29392165b5bdfe8f011dca97f1e/lib/util.js#L189-L198):

```
function formatValue(ctx, value, recurseTimes) {
  // Provide a hook for user-specified inspect functions.
  // Check that value is an object with an inspect function on it
  if (value && typeof value.inspect === 'function' &&
      // Filter out the util module, it's inspect function is special
      value.inspect !== exports.inspect &&
      // Also filter out any prototype objects using the circular check.
      !(value.constructor && value.constructor.prototype === value)) {
    return String(value.inspect(recurseTimes));
  }
```

I.e., it's only when `inspect` exists and is a function that triggers the behavior.

Comment: Nice find. Don't suppose you know of any other things like this. It took me ages to track down this bug and I don't want to fall foul of something like it again.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. I can't find anything else in `util.js` that looks fishy, either.

Comment: I'll mark you as the answer because you have found the cause. Cheers

Comment: @JamesBrooks I also took 2 hours to find this. I was setting properties on an object who has a `inspect` method. `console.log` never showed it. I debugged for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If an object has an `inspect` property **and** it is a function, `console.log` prints its return value.

```
$ node
> console.log({ inspect: function() { return 'hi'; } });
hi
```

If we look at [the source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6.20/lib/util.js#L154-162), we'll see that there's no way to avoid this behavior.  If an object's `inspect` is a function, `console.log` will print its return value.

---

Note that in Node 0.6.x and before, `console.log` doesn't actually print `undefined`, it just prints a blank line.  You'd only see `undefined` if you're doing this in the [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).

Comment: I'm not doing it in a REPL. It's a file, see the other answer.

Comment: @JamesBrooks: Sorry, that was true in Node 0.6.x, but not 0.8.x.  I've noted that.